# How to stop animation on clicking the layout in android?

Tags: android, onclick

I have the following piece of code...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    i.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation);

    i.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) i.getBackground();
            anim.start(); 
        }
    });
}
```

I want to add another listener on the background/layout so that when someone clicks on the image, the animation gets started and when someone clicks on the background it stops looping.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your animation drawable to a class variable. Then, start and stop it from onClickListeners hooked up to the ImageView and the background.

```
AnimationDrawable anim;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    i.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation); 
    anim = (AnimationDrawable) i.getBackground();
    i.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            anim.start(); 

        }
    });

    // Or whatever type of layout it is
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
    myLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            anim.stop(); 

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts bro :) but not getting it going..!!

Comment: Plz try again if u can,,,i got some hint from ur code,,,first of all
the code R.id.mylayout is not working..?????

Comment: hmm,,, there is error i have tried to edit it someway,,although dont know,,this is code which i have added in addition

Comment: RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
  rl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    AnimationDrawable anim1 = (AnimationDrawable) i.getBackground();
    anim1.stop();

   }
  });
 }

Comment: Sorry, that's a placeholder for your actual layout's id. You will need to give the layout an id the same way your ImageView has the id imageView1.

Comment: Awesome work ,,,thanks thanks for that bro :))))))....one thing more i wana ask how could i reset its state,,means i want when i click there it not just stops but gets to initial stage..??

Comment: You cannot use findViewById(R.layout.activity_main) because it is a layout, not an id. Use my code. Then, in your activity_main.xml, set the parent layout's id as android:id="@+id/my_layout"

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685327/how-to-reset-animationdrawable

Comment: Yahh i got ur point and It has been solved ...!! Thanks for the best efforts..!! 
one thing more i wana ask how could i reset its state,,means i want when i click there it not just stops but gets to initial stage..??