# OutOfMemoryError when trying to load multiple frame-by-frame animations one after the other in Android

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory, animationdrawable

I have a couple of frame-by-frame animations (`animation-list`). Loading any one of them to an ImageView is not a problem. The problem occurs when I try to load a different animation in the same ImageView.

```
private void startAnimation(int anim) {
    mImageView.setImageResource(anim);
    ((AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).start();
}
```

This was the code that I was using. After getting  `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` after calling the function more than one time, I added the following code to try and clear the `AnimationDrawable` and the `ImageView`.

```
private void startAnimation(int anim) {
    if (mImageView.getDrawable() != null) { //trying to clear if it's not empty
        if (((AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).isRunning()) {
             ((AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).stop();
             ((AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).selectDrawable(0);
        }
        mImageView.setImageResource(null);
    }
    //starting animation here
    mImageView.setImageResource(anim);
    ((AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).start();
}
```

Well, this didn't work. I've tried the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082181/animation-drawable-causing-outofmemoryerror-on-second-run-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685327/how-to-reset-animationdrawable) and they also didn't work. I still keep getting `OutOfMemoryError`. 
This is how I call the `startAnimation` function.

```
startAnimation(R.drawable.anim1);//works fine
startAnimation(R.drawable.anim2);//OutOfMemoryError
 ...
```

So, how do I free the memory, and load the animation? Note that I want to do this over and over again.

Comment: I think that just the garbage collector cannon remove old animation resource when app loads a new.

Comment: I also tried `System.gc()` to no avail. What do you suggest?

Comment: Imma sorry, I haven't computer to find solution. I only wrote a possible bug reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work by adding `mImageView.getDrawable().setVisible(false, true)` before starting a new animation.